# Zend 2 Form request post not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm learning Zend 2 framework and for a Form i need to test if my request is a post and if it is to get it

on the tutorial : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html

they use this

```
$request = $this->getRequest();  // this is a AbstractActionController
if ($request->isPost()) {
$album = new Album();
$form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
$form->setData($request->getPost());
...
}
```

i have almost the same thing exept that i can't access the post method's on the request
 any idea why ?

Comment: You have an error ? And, what's inside your view and class `*Form` ?

Comment: i'm coding on netbeans and he doesn't even found the isPost() or getPost() method

Comment: What error you get while doing this?

Comment: your code is perfect on isPost() as well as getRequest(). check the apache error log and post the real problem!